# Not able to get system data at the end of transformation step

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I wants to log transformation start time and end time into table. But I am getting error **Field [start_date] is required and couldn't be found!**.

Following steps I did.

Step 1 : Get Transformation name and system date from **Get System Data** as 
         Transformation Start_Date.

Step 2 : Use **Table Input** to get count of records in table A.

Step 3 : Use **Filter** to check if table A is empty (Count = 0), if empty then 
         copy of data from table B to Table A.

Step 4 : IF empty then control goes to **Table Input** to select all 
         data from table B.

Step 5 : Use **Table Output** To insert data from **Table Input**.

Step 6 : Get system date from **Get System Data** as transformation End_date.

Step 7 : Use Table Output step to insert data into log table, Into this step I 
         am inserting Transformation name,Start Date and End Date.

Can someone let me know where I am wrong. I am not able to get Start Date at the end of transformation. Following is the Diagram.

[Transformation Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIuOE.png)

Comment: If you preview your output step, do you see a valid date in 'Start_Date'?

Comment: no, I did not see any date. Do I tried with set variable and get variable also but that one also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Table Input step ignores records that were generated before. In your diagram "Get_Transformation_name_and_start_time"  generates a single row that is passed to the next step (the Table Input one) and then it's not propagated any further.

You can use a single "Get System Info" step at the end of your transformation to obtain start/end date (in your diagram that would be Get_Transformation_end_time 2). To get transformation start date you can use "with system date (fixed)" value. It will return the system time, determined at the start of the transformation, that will be common for all rows. You can use "system date (variable)" as an end timestamp (in case of more than one record you'll have to take max of these values).

It's probably worth looking at standard Pentaho logging options: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.08+Transformation+Settings#.08TransformationSettings-Logging , you can set-up a DB conection and a table that will store transformation execution data "out of the box".